# load image from webview (Web Engine) to imageviewer in javafx

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

i have created a web view in javafx and loaded a webpage in it. The webpage contain and image which is generated randomly from the server. Once the page is loaded i try to run the javascript to get the url of the image and try to apply it to image viewer but the url makes another request to server for another image and it render different image but i want the same image which is loaded first on the webview. i do not want  my web viewer should request to another image and render it.

First.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.web.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>


<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" fx:controller="com.jb.FirstController">
   <children>
      <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.3732638888888889" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="3.0" prefHeight="372.0" prefWidth="578.0">
    <items>
          <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="100.0">
               <children>
                  <WebView fx:id="webview" layoutX="6.0" layoutY="10.0" prefHeight="346.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
               </children>
            </AnchorPane>
          <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="100.0">
               <children>
                  <ImageView fx:id="imageview" fitHeight="311.0" fitWidth="256.0" layoutX="23.0" layoutY="23.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" />
               </children>
            </AnchorPane>
        </items>
      </SplitPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

FirstController.java

```
package com.jb;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.concurrent.Worker;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageViewBuilder;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;

/**
 * FXML Controller class
 *
 * @author admin
 */
public class FirstController implements Initializable {

@FXML
WebView webview;

@FXML
ImageView imageview;

private WebEngine webengine;


@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    webengine = webview.getEngine();

    //once the page is loaded this event occures
    webengine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener((obs,oldValue,newValue) -> {

    //if page loaded successfully
        if(newValue==Worker.State.SUCCEEDED)
        {
            //executing script to get the image src from webview
            String img=(String)webengine.getDocument().getElementById("addimage").getAttribute("src");
            System.out.println("img:"+img);

            //img variable has the value 'http://localhost:8080/WebApplication10/getNewAddImage'
    //'getNewAddImage' is a servlet which accept get request
            //this servlet gives a random image from backend 

    //setting the url in image view
    imageview.setImage(new Image(img));
        }                         
    });


    //requesting to index.jsp to load in webview
    webengine.load("http://localhost:8080/WebApplication10/index.jsp");
}    

}
```

Test.java

```
package com.jb;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author admin
 */
public class Test extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("First.fxml"));

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

}
```

i need to load the same image which is first loaded in the webview 
i do not won't to request to new image

Any help would be  appreciated

Thanks

Comment: We are not a code writing service. Please refer to [How to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Have you tried to do any research? What have you tried? Questions here should have a clear problem/question, with research shown, and a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Comment: thanks, i have added source code for the question